# Xamarin Forms unable to resolve Azure storage from nuget package

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-blob-storage, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to upload a blob to azure using a shared access signature. I have the token and added the nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage to my project. I've tried both version 7.0.0 and 7.0.1-preview. 
For some reason I'm unable to resolve the reference when creating an instance of CloudBlobContainer. Also I've tried to just type the using statement but no luck. All azure documentation points to a version 4.4.0-preview, is this the one I should be using?

azure doc ref https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/storage-xamarin-blob-storage/

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just guess that the docs are outdated with the 4.4.0-preview link instead of a link to the NuGet package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/

`CloudBlobContainer` seems to be within the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` namespace.

I would check to ensure that you actually installed the NuGet package as it may have failed silently with other projects.

EX: http://screencast.com/t/FLhztkeu

Comment: Some more reading on the topic, it seems to be an issue with the PCL profile. My current is 78 so need to find a match in my Xamarin Forms project targeting iOS and Android

Comment: Awesome PCL profile 111 and WindowsAzure.Storage 7.0.1-preview seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the PCL profile worked for me. Bizarre.

After installing the NuGet package, you actually need to change the profile on your Xamarin project. You can do this by going to the shared project -> Options -> General – > C#

[image]

- Change the Current Profile to  **PCL 4.5 – Profile111** (I have no idea
  of what this does.)
- You need to retarget your NuGet packages for this new profile now.
  Right click on Packages within the shared project, and you’ll have 5
  options here.
- Retarget will be available. Click that. (Not shown here, as I’ve
  already retargeted)

[image]

- Rebuild your project

**How I figured this out**

I stumbled across [this Xamarin forum post,](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58912/xamarin-forms-pcl-not-shared-app-photos-azure-blob-storage) where someone had the exact same issue. One user pointed us towards a [bug report](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/136), where PCL references were not added automatically via NuGet package installation. They recommended retargeting, and it worked! Now I can include the using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;  namespace.

[I have a blog post with more info on this.](http://www.davevoyles.com/getting-azure-storage-blob-work-xamarin-forms/)